# form tag wraps all content after it

Tags: javascript, html, macos, dom, safari

I'm seeing some odd behavior in Safari 7.1 (9537.85.10.17.1) on Mac OS X 10.9.5. When creating new DOM, the form tag always wrap any content after it.

```
var html = '<html><body> <form></form> <div>bam</div> </body></html>';
var doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  #document
  <html>
    <body>
      <form>
        <div>bam</div>
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Can anyone confirm? Which tree do I bark on to get the oddity resolved?

As a work around:

```
var html = '<html><body> <div><form></form></div> <div>bam</div> </body></html>';
var doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  #document
  <html>
    <body>
      <div>
        <form></form>
      </div>
      <div>bam</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var html = '<html><body> <div><form></form> <div>bam</div></div> </body></html>';
    var doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
      #document
      <html>
        <body>
         <div>
          <form>
           </form>
            <div>bam</div>
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: This does not answer the questions asked. It just suggests a workaround, without even saying why it would be better than the one in the question.